# How to create a dll with SDK's static lib and header file & load ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, dll, static-libraries, ctypes

I am involved in a research project that plans on using a certain SDK to get the raw image data from a camera (that is operating with the SDK's code) onto Python using ctypes.

The SDK utilizes C++ and unfortunately does not come with a dll, so apparently I need to create one manually by compiling the SDK's provided static libraries and header files and one way or another get the created dll to be loadable from python using ctypes.

Unfortunately I know very little about C++, which in the beginning was not really a problem as originally this project was thought to need very little of it (with the dll assumed to be provided). That being said, I have been looking for guides on creating dll's with given static libraries and header files but haven't had much luck finding resources that I can understand very well from the introductory C++ videos and tutorials I've gone through.

I was hoping that there would be some people on here that may know a straightforward approach on how to compile these pre-existing header files and static library into a dll, and what the next step would be in terms of getting this dll to be loadable from ctypes in order to call the function contained in the static library.

Any responses or guidance in the matter are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your only option is to create a wrapper DLL which exposes some C functions that you must write.  Those functions will call the C++ static library code to perform the work.  Basically, you need to create a bridge.  Once you have that DLL built, you can use it from Python with ctypes.

Comment: Don't post a large block of paragraph. It's not readable. Break it down and make it easy to read.

Comment: If it was C, you could probably create an empty DLL project, import the static lib and create a DEF file listing the things you want to export. But unfortunately C++ name mangling means you don't know the names of the things you want to export.